# springMVC can't receive full json data

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm trying to use $.ajax and `@RequestBody`, but when I use it to pass Integer type. It can't read the data and print `null`. What kind of data `@RequestBody` can receive?

Here is my code:

```
var user = {
    "username" : "test",
    "password" : "test",
    "age" : 1
};
$.ajax({
    url: "/test1",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {
        alert("success")
    }
})
```

and this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test1")
public String test2(@RequestBody User user) {

    //Can't receive the Param.
    //   console result : null
    System.out.println(user.getAge());

    //Nothing wrong
    //console result: 
    //                  username:  test
    //                  password:  test
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()); 
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());
    return "test";
}
```

Here is User class:

```
public class User {
    private Integer age;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    //Setting and Getting
}
```

Comment: How does your User class look like?

Comment: your variable names should be same as your model's field name,  It seems  in your json object there is you not pass `age`  so it always getting `null` result

Comment: In your code, you are setting the ID param, while printing the `user.getAge()`

Comment: I have revised my code and added my User class.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the issue is.  In User class:

```
public class User {
    //It should be `int`
    private Integer age;
}
```

`int` is a base data type. `Integer` is a wrapper class. I need to transform data type.